# Set default date on a textbox in aspx (not codebehind!)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have this but it's not working:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:d}")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: # can be used only in a databound context. You can try <%= for a client control. The answer is surely already present.

Comment: ok, I changed it with text='<%=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")%>' but now the textbox shows the code as it is

Comment: I told for a client control... It's not asp

Comment: So there isn't a way to achieve this on aspx? Only by code behind?

Comment: You can use javascript also. Add ID property to TextBox and set current date by jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call databind on page_load if you are going to bind data to Controls that way.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is the only way you are going to bind data. You have to at least add this or don't use an `asp:TextBox`